# How to fix this code, logical problem I guess

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp, racket

I'm in the university, first year programing, so far so good then I stuck with this exercise, I have to do a function that:

```
function(n1 n2) = n1 * n2
```

but without using the * operator.

What we can use is the previous function that adds two numbers.

```
;Takes two numbers as input and return the sum between them

;Number Number -> Number

;(sum 2 3) = 5

     (define (sum n1 n2)
        (cond
            [(zero? n1) n2]
            [(positive? n1) (sum (sub1 n1) (add1 n2))]
      ))
```

The trick on don't use the + or * in this is that we have to do it with a recursion function.

So here is what I made and this function have to return the multiplication of two numbers, so we know that a multiplication 3 * 2 is 3 + 3 or 2 + 2 + 2, so that is what I try to make here but I can't figure out more than this

```
;Takes two numbers as input and return the multiplication between them

;Number Number -> Number

;(mult 3 2) = 6

      (define (mult n1 n2)
         (cond
             [(zero? n1) n2]
             [(positive? n1) (mult (sub1 n1) (sum n1 n2))]
        ))
```

The output of (mult 3 2) is 8, which clearly is not doing what I need to do.

---

Solved!

```
     (define (mult n1 n2)
         (cond
             [(or (zero? n1) (zero? n2)) 0] ;verify if zero is one of the inputs and return it
             [(eq? 1 n1) n2] ;if n1 is one return n2
             [(eq? 1 n2) n1] ;if n2 is one return n1
             [(positive? n1) (sum n2 (mult (sub1 n1) n2))] ;if it none of the adove, add n2 n1Times to itself
      ))
```

Thanks! @Barmar @coredump

Comment: Are you sure about `[(zero? n1) n2]`? Would you expect the result of `(mult 0 2)` to be 2?

Comment: haha I feel stupid rigth now for not see that

Comment: It's a good lesson, though. When a recursive function is not behaving as expected, one of the first things to check is whether the base cases really make sense.

Comment: Your recursion step is also not correct.`(mult 4 5)` is not the same as `(mult 3 6)`.

Comment: `(mult 4 5) == (mult 2 10) == (mult 1 20) == 20`. See the pattern?

Comment: That only works when `n1` is even. When it's odd you need an extra step: `(mult 5 5) == (sum 5 (mult 4 5))`.

Comment: I see, but when you have a little fo time would you explain me a little more? Because I can copy and paste but I need to learn it

Comment: @Barmar Halving one term at each step of recursion is interesting to implement and better complexity-wise, but I don't think this is what is expected from the assignment.

Comment: The alternative is `(mult 4 5) == (sum 5 (mult 3 5)) == (sum 5 (sum 5 (mult 2 5))) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: here is a trace of execution of the expected recursive function with arguments 5 and 3, where each nested level correspond to a recursive invocation of `MULT`:

```
  0: (MULT 5 3)
    1: (MULT 4 3)
      2: (MULT 3 3)
        3: (MULT 2 3)
          4: (MULT 1 3)
            5: (MULT 0 3)
            5: MULT returned 0
          4: MULT returned 3
        3: MULT returned 6
      2: MULT returned 9
    1: MULT returned 12
  0: MULT returned 15
```

Note that the depth of the recursion here is 5, but you could be clever and have it be 3 instead.